# Removing leading zeros from pandas.core.series.Series

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have a pandas.core.series.Series with data

```
0    [00115840, 00110005, 001000033, 00116000...
1    [00267285, 00263627, 00267010, 0026513...
2                             [00335595, 00350750]
```

I want to remove leading zeros from the series.I tried

```
x.astype('int64')
```

But got error message

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Can you suggest me how to do this in python 3.x?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If want list of `string`s convert to list of `integers`s use `list comprehension`:

```
s = pd.Series([[int(y) for y in x] for x in s], index=s.index)
```

```
s = s.apply(lambda x: [int(y) for y in x])
```

Sample:

```
a = [['00115840', '00110005', '001000033', '00116000'],
     ['00267285', '00263627', '00267010', '0026513'],
     ['00335595', '00350750']]

s = pd.Series(a)
print (s)
0    [00115840, 00110005, 001000033, 00116000]
1      [00267285, 00263627, 00267010, 0026513]
2                         [00335595, 00350750]
dtype: object

s = s.apply(lambda x: [int(y) for y in x])
print (s)
0    [115840, 110005, 1000033, 116000]
1      [267285, 263627, 267010, 26513]
2                     [335595, 350750]
dtype: object
```

EDIT:

If want `integer`s only you can flatten values and cast to `int`s:

```
s = pd.Series([item for sublist in s for item in sublist]).astype(int)
```

Alternative solution:

```
import itertools
s = pd.Series(list(itertools.chain(*s))).astype(int)

print (s)
0     115840
1     110005
2    1000033
3     116000
4     267285
5     263627
6     267010
7      26513
8     335595
9     350750
dtype: int32
```

**Timings**:

```
a = [['00115840', '00110005', '001000033', '00116000'],
     ['00267285', '00263627', '00267010', '0026513'],
     ['00335595', '00350750']]

s = pd.Series(a)
s = pd.concat([s]*1000).reset_index(drop=True)
```

```
In [203]: %timeit pd.Series([[int(y) for y in x] for x in s], index=s.index)
100 loops, best of 3: 4.66 ms per loop

In [204]: %timeit s.apply(lambda x: [int(y) for y in x])
100 loops, best of 3: 5.13 ms per loop

#cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ sol
In [205]: %%timeit
     ...: v = pd.Series(np.concatenate(s.values.tolist()))
     ...: v.astype(int).groupby(s.index.repeat(s.str.len())).agg(pd.Series.tolist)
     ...: 
1 loop, best of 3: 226 ms per loop

#Wen solution
In [211]: %timeit pd.Series(s.apply(pd.Series).stack().astype(int).groupby(level=0).apply(list))
1 loop, best of 3: 1.12 s per loop
```

Solutions with flatenning (idea of @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ):

```
In [208]: %timeit pd.Series([item for sublist in s for item in sublist]).astype(int)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.55 ms per loop

In [209]: %timeit pd.Series(list(itertools.chain(*s))).astype(int)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.2 ms per loop

#cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ sol
In [210]: %timeit pd.Series(np.concatenate(s.values.tolist()))
100 loops, best of 3: 7.71 ms per loop
```

Comment: what is `x` @jezrael

Comment: @pyd - it is lambda or list comprehension variable.

Answer (score 4):

```
s=pd.Series(s.apply(pd.Series).astype(int).values.tolist())
s
Out[282]: 
0    [1, 2]
1    [3, 4]
dtype: object
```

Data input

```
s=pd.Series([['001','002'],['003','004']])
```

Update: Thanks for Jez and cold point it out :-)

```
pd.Series(s.apply(pd.Series).stack().astype(int).groupby(level=0).apply(list))
Out[317]: 
0    [115840, 110005, 1000033, 116000]
1      [267285, 263627, 267010, 26513]
2                     [335595, 350750]
dtype: object
```

Comment: I think your solution failed if not same size of lists, check my sample data. :(

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ fixed :-)

Comment: @Wen - added to timings.

Answer (score 2):

Flatten your data with `np.concatenate`  -

```
s

0    [00115840, 36869, 262171, 39936]
1     [00267285, 92055, 93704, 11595]
2                  [00335595, 119272]
Name: 1, dtype: object

v = pd.Series(np.concatenate(s.tolist()))
```

Or (thanks to jezrael for the suggestion), using `.values.tolist` which is faster -

```
v = pd.Series(np.concatenate(s.values.tolist()))
```

```
v

0    00115840
1       36869
2      262171
3       39936
4    00267285
5       92055
6       93704
7       11595
8    00335595
9      119272
dtype: object
```

Now, what you're doing with `astype` should work -

```
v.astype(int)

0    115840
1     36869
2    262171
3     39936
4    267285
5     92055
6     93704
7     11595
8    335595
9    119272
dtype: int64
```

If you have data as floats, use `astype(float)` instead.

---

If you want to, you could reshape the result back to its original format using `groupby` + `agg` -

```
v.astype(int).groupby(s.index.repeat(s.str.len())).agg(pd.Series.tolist)

0    [115840, 36869, 262171, 39936]
1     [267285, 92055, 93704, 11595]
2                  [335595, 119272]
dtype: object
```

Comment: `pd.Series(np.concatenate(s.values.tolist()))` ?

Comment: @jezrael `s.tolist()` works, or am I missing something? :-)

Comment: It is faster,  ;)

Comment: @jezrael Awesome! Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a more crisp solution, you could try following:
Assuming a is the original series.

```
b = a.explode().astype(int)
a = b.groupby(b.index).agg(list)
```

Albeit, this is slower than solutions posted by @cs95 and @jezrael

Answer (score 1):

```
#where x is a series
x = x.str.lstrip('0')
```

Answer (score 0):

Below lines should work if you have mixed dtype

df['col'] = df['col'].apply(lambda x:x.lstrip('0') if type(x) == str else x)